# htaccess exclude file require auth

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, except

I would like to require an auth for all files except index.php

here is my code but I don't know what's wrong...

```
AuthName "Restricted area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
IndexIgnore     */Network?Trash?Folder */Temporary?Items

Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 192.168.0.254
Allow from ::1

Satisfy Any


<Files "*">
Require valid-user
</Files>

<Files "\index.php">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all 
</Files>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490920/how-would-i-require-a-password-for-all-files-except-one-using-htaccess?rq=1

Comment: i've already done that but it ask me an auth every times..

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd

<Files "*">
Require valid-user
</Files>

<Files "index.php">
Allow from all 
Satisfy any
</Files>
```

Comment: but when i tip index1.html, i didn t require any auth !!!

`AuthName "Restricted area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
IndexIgnore  */Network?Trash?Folder */Temporary?Items

Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 192.168.0.254
Allow from ::1


<Files "*">
Require valid-user
</Files>

<Files "index.php">
Allow from all 
Satisfy any
</Files>

<Files "">
Allow from all 
Satisfy any
</Files>`

Comment: Maybe your browser cached the authentication, did you try cleaning the browser cache?

Comment: in fact the code bellow didn't work at all, it ask me every time an auth, even if index.php is called... i used this instead: `AuthName "Restricted area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
IndexIgnore  */Network?Trash?Folder */Temporary?Items

Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 192.168.0.254
Allow from ::1

<Files "*">
 Require valid-user
</Files>


<Files "index.php">
  Allow from all 
  Satisfy any
</Files>
<Files "">
  Allow from all 
  Satisfy any
</Files>` but it didn t ask me an auth if index1.html is called

Comment: can you explain what the problem was?