# .htaccess Exclude specific files from authentication

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to exclude a specific file from authentication. e.g host: test.com. I want to exclude test.com/unsecure.php

This is my .htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "TEST"
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/TEST/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: You can find here how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603568/password-protect-a-specific-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess exclude file require auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216816/htaccess-exclude-file-require-auth)

Answer (score 0):

Got it now. Thanks

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "TEST"
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/TEST/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

<Files "unsecure.php">
   Satisfy Any
   Allow from all
</Files>
```